# Programatically invoking tap gesture for UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've created a UIView programatically.
I've added tap gesture action programatically.

I would like to invoke the tap programatically.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
MyUIView *myView = [[MyUIView alloc] init];

UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTap = 
  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                          action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

[myView.addGestureRecognizer:oneTap];
```

Now I would like to invoke a tap event on this myView.

How can I do that programatically?

Comment: Can you just call handleSingleTap: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to just call `handleSingleTap` method just like you can call other methods,

`[self handleSingleTap: oneTap];`